# How to set Links to “Open in new tab” by default?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

When inserting link, SharePoint identifies that it is a link and it opens a pop up to add text to display and web address. There is an option under LINK to check whether the links will open in a new tab or not. Is there any way where we can check this checkbox by default all the time?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer to your question is No.

This is not possible using SharePoint OOTB capabilities.

Comment: Is it possible to do using JQuery?

Comment: You cannot make the checkbox selection by default. However you can add the jQuery code on your page which will get all the hyperlinks in your particular webpart(recommended) or complete page content and set the `target`  property to `_blank` which will cause all links to open in new tab.

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161672/make-links-in-a-specific-div-open-in-new-tab). Here you should pass the `div` element ID for targeted area only. because there are lot of other anchor tags (hyperlinks) on SharePoint Page and that should not get disturbed with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge there is no settings make open in new tab to be checked by default. You can post in [UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration) about this feature.